# can't access php file in webserver from browser

Tags: web-server, domain, godaddy

I have a go daddy web server tied with a domain. Recently I moved the domain to a different DNS and point to a different web server, therefore leaving the web server on go daddy domainless. I tried to access the file on the web server via IP address but I can't (it gives me a 404 error). I can however FTP to the webserver via the IP address. What should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you might be running into one or two of the following:

1) Your web browser has cached the old IP address.  Try a different browser (like Firefox if you use MSIE, or Safari if you use Firefox on the mac), one that you haven't been to the web site with in a while.  You could also try to flush your DNS cache on your client (dscacheutil on a mac, ipconfig on a windows machine), but if the nameserver you use is caching, you may just have to wait.

2) Going to a website using the IP address only really works if the server uses separate IP addresses for each website - which I kind of doubt that godaddy does.  So try using telnet, from whatever command line you have (cmd.exe in windows, terminal.app in Mac, bash in linux)

```
$ telnet
telnet> open <ipaddress> 80
GET /path_to_file.php HTTP/1.0
Host: your.domain.name
(hit enter twice)
```

If you get the result you expect, then it's there, you just need to wait for DNS to refresh.

Comment: I actually changed the DNS a month back.. also doing open <ipaddress> 80 gives me Connected to p3nlhg166c1166.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Right, after you get the "Connected to....Escape Character is.." stuff, type in "GET ..." and the rest of it